# Implementing a Child Data Structure in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, oop, react-native

I'm currently trying to wrap my head around how a typical data structure would be implemented in React. Using a queue as an example, from what I understand, if I created it in Java, I could just define the function in this Javascript-translated format:

```
class Queue extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {message: "Test"}
  }

  queue(el) {
    let arr = this.state.arr.slice();
    arr.push(el);
    return arr;
  }

  dequeue = (el) => {
    let arr = this.state.arr.slice(1, this.state.arr.length);
    return arr;
  }

  next = () => {
    let arr = this.state.arr.slice();
    return arr[1];
  }

  last = () => {
    let arr = this.state.arr.slice();
    return arr[arr.length - 1];
  }
}
```

and access it in a main() method. In this case however, I would be using a parent Component, an example of which can be seen below:

```
class Main extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {queue: new Queue()};
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.queue); 
    //displays the queue with its listed functions properly

    this.state.queue(new Date());
    //ERROR: 'cannot read property "slice" of undefined'
  }
}
```

So I can figure out the obvious occurrence of the *Main* class accessing the function *queue()* from the *Queue* class, but having **this** being bound to the *Main* class instead of the *Queue* class as intended.

So my question is this: using the ES6 arrow syntax, how do I maintain a binding of the **this** used in the *Main* class to the child instance of queue instead of to the *Main* class that calls the method?

In other words, how do I ensure the **this.state.arr** variable being accessed refers to the **arr** stored in the **queue** instance of *Queue* rather than the undeclared **arr** in the state of the *Main* class?

I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate question, but searching didn't get me any answers to this particular case so your help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: As Sidney pointed out below, I made a stupid mistake and omitted **arr** from my state in the *Queue* component. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting actually isn't related to `this` binding, and it would occur if you use the `Queue` class outside of React.

```js
class Queue {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {message: "Test"}
  }

  queue(el) {
    let arr = this.state.arr.slice();
    arr.push(el);
    return arr;
  }

  dequeue = (el) => {
    let arr = this.state.arr.slice(1, this.state.arr.length);
    return arr;
  }

  next = () => {
    let arr = this.state.arr.slice();
    return arr[1];
  }

  last = () => {
    let arr = this.state.arr.slice();
    return arr[arr.length - 1];
  }
}

const ticketLine = new Queue()
ticketLine.queue('Bob')
ticketLine.queue('Sarah')
```

(Notice that `extends Component` and `super()` have been removed)

The error occurs on the first line of `queue()`, you're trying to access `this.state.arr` but you never defined it. So calling `.slice()` on undefined throws an error.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply Sidney, I noticed that just now and I'm definitely not surprised I made such a stupid mistake. I am however wondering about something else: since I never mount "Queue" in the "Main" class, when I input the following: console.log(this.state.queue);
    this.state.queue.queue(new Date());
    console.log(this.state.queue); the arr variable in the queue state is never updated. Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: The `arr` variable in the Queue state doesn't change because you're using `slice` to copy the array in `Queue.queue` before adding the new element. This basically copies the array, adds an element to the copy, and discards the copy, since you never do anything else with the copy. You should store plain arrays or objects in React's state, not full class instances. You can create helper functions that take the current state and return a new state. You also might want to look into [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) for state management, and just have React do the rendering.